# Higher model accuracy for TensorFlow on Google Colab GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gpu

When i run my simple Neural Network model on MNIST dataset, on my Macbook, the accuracy is about %0.85.
but when i copy the same code (everything's the same, like epoch numbers etc) on Google Colab, with their decent GPUs, i get an accuracy of about %0.95, is there any rationale around it ?
Regards

Comment: a difference in one tenth of a percent isn't something to worry about.  might be a train/test split- do you set your seed for each run?

Comment: Are you sure about 0.85/0.95 percent? Because that would be a really bad model. Maybe you mean 85/95 percent.

Comment: Yes, I mean 85/95 percent (Different notations) .